# Check is changed value in text box using class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text boxes with .numeric class. I want check value had change or not after the edit that value.

I found this code after google.

```
var previousValue = $("#elm").val();
$("#elm").keyup(function(e) {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    if(currentValue != previousValue) {
         previousValue = currentValue;
         alert("Value changed!");
    }
});
```

But this code will work for only one text field (with id `#elm`). What should I do if I want to make it work for multiple fields (sharing the class `numeric`) ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is pretty damn obvious!

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. Finally i find the best solution. I is easy. We can use change function in jquery. It function fire after change the value. That i wanted.

```
$('.numeric').change(function () {
   alert('Changed');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for that:

```
$(".numeric").each(function(){
    $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
});

$(".numeric").keyup(function(e) {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();

    var preVal = $(this).data("value");
    alert(preVal);

    if(currentValue != preVal) {
         $(this).data("value", currentValue);
         preVal = currentValue;
         alert("Value changed!");
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/HLwCC/2/)

<sup>Try typing `55` in one field, `66` in another, and `77` in another and notice the previous value remains different for each field</sup>

Answer (score 1):

How about just changing the selector to match

```
$(".numeric").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.isTrigger) $(this).data('val', this.value);
    if(this.value != $(this).data('val')) {
         $(this).data('val', this.value);
         alert("Value changed!");
    }
}).trigger('keyup');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6frnD/4/)

And instead of just copy pasting code from Google, spend a few hours on https://learn.jquery.com/ and learn how it works.

Comment: Switching the selector won't work properly if multiple inputs are returned... they would still share a the previousValue variable.

Comment: @SamR - I guess I have to post a real answer then

Answer (score 1):

very simple:

```
var currentValue ;

$(".numeric").keydown(function(e) {
        currentValue = $(this).val();

    });

    $(".numeric").keyup(function(e) {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        if(currentValue != previousValue) {
             previousValue = currentValue;
             alert("Value changed!");
        }
    });
```

here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6rUG2/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'change' trigger will cover also the case when user copy-paste values in your field(s) by mouse actions

```
$(".numeric").each(function(){
    $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
});

$(".numeric").on('change', function(e) {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    var preVal = $(this).data("value");
    if(currentValue != preVal) {
     preVal = currentValue;
     alert("Value changed!");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLwCC/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".numeric").each(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-pre_value', $(this).val());
});

$(".numeric").bind('keyup', function(){
  var pre_value = $(this).attr('data-pre_value');
  var current_value = $(this).val();
  if(pre_value != current_value){
    alert('value has changed'); 
  }

});
```

now, you can change bind event. you can bind event on blur or focus out.